# decode textarea box value in extjs form

Tags: extjs

I have to decode my textbox value. I am using the code below

```
{
   xtype: 'textareafield',
   id: 'Reason',
   itemId: 'Reason',
   width: 100,
   name: 'Reason',
   fieldLabel: 'Reason / Comments ',
   displayField: 'Reason',
   allowBlank: false,
   anchor: '100%',
   listeners:{
      afterrender:function(value) {
          //alert(value);
          var reason = Ext.getCmp('Reason').getValue();
          //alert(reason);
          if(reason!='') {
              var reas = Ext.decode(reason);
              Ext.getCmp('Reason').setValue(reas);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

If  I uncomment alert(value) here, it returns value in
alert(reason) and decodes my textbox value but if I
comment alert(value), it returns empty in alert(reason),
so doesn't decode my textbox value

Comment: or Please suggest me another method

Answer (score 1):

Because the **[afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-event-afterrender)** event returns as first param a reference. It will work if you type: `alert(value.getValue())`

But you should really take a look at the **[API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/)** A textarea has no `displayField` at all

Comment: same problem in this alert(value.getValue()) also. But I want value in my "reason" variable without displaying alert box.Its only returns value in "reason" variable, if I use alert otherwise not..